# mysql - on update cascade with foreign key with autoincrement

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following scenario in InnoDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `report_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `option_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `report_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `options_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id_fk`) REFERENCES `reports` (`report_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

reports and options are 1 to 1 relationship. I want to be able to update `report_id` from INT to BIGINT. Since it is autoincrement, I have to remove that first before updating the column, I thought that since the foreign key in `options` table has `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, it would take care of the secondary tables when doing the update on `reports`.

I tried doing:

```
ALTER TABLE reports DROP PRIMARY KEY, MODIFY COLUMN report_id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

But I get a foreign key constraint error, which the message in InnoDB:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
230612 11:51:05 Error in foreign key constraint of table [DB name]/options:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "options_ibfk" FOREIGN KEY ("report_id_fk") REFERENCES "reports" ("report_id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
The index in the foreign key in table is "report_id_fk"
```

My question is, can I update the parent table (`reports`) primary key **without having to drop the foreign key constraint on the child table (`options`) temporarily?** I would like to keep the `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I have this scenario with multiple tables referencing `report_id` in the same way.

Comment: `ON UPDATE CASCADE` copies changes in values, it won't copy changes in datatype.

Comment: the cascade is not intended for structural changes, i would drop the constraint, make the change, lastly recreate the constraint.

Comment: I suggest you just turn off FK checking temporarily.